# Automatically expose underlying files in iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, photos, websites

My wife and I use a blog on Blogspot to post pictures and videos of our kids for our far-flung relations.

Recently, we have had issues with posting videos from iPhoto to the blog. The blog uses a standard browser interface to get to the content.

After a lot of investigation, I found that the issue is that the iPhoto library (package) is exposing the **thumbnail** of the video to the interface, not the **actual video**.  The website can't process the thumbnail as a video (obviously) and this is causing us all sorts of grief.

This apparently worked fine until a recent update within the past month or so (per my wife).

Is there any way around this or am I stuck with having to manually locate and migrate the files to a temporary folder so we can share them?

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Reveal in Finder > Original File.

It will open a new Finder window with some obscure path, but don't worry, you don't really have to deal with that.

Just grab the file, drop it on the file dialog sheet...

[image: Dragging file]

and vuala! Your file has been selected. This little trick applies to any file and any native file dialog in OSX.

[image: File selected]

Quick and easy.

Note: As an extra tip, you can also drag the file directly to any "Choose File" button in Safari.

[image: Choose file button accepting file]

So there you go! First show the file, then drag it to the file picker. No temporary folders, moving or even remembering a path involved. Hope it helps!